# Función fetchAll() no la reconoce el servidor

Tags: php

En local si me funciona la función fetchAll, vi y tiene que ver con la versión del PHP o que falta un controlador, el servidor es muy limitado y no puedo actualizar la versión de PHP ya probre con `fetch_assoc` y `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` y aun no me funciona. Le coloco `fetch()` y ya no me da error, pero me devuelve un solo resultado y no todos

```
  $data['usuarios'] = $database->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios u LEFT JOIN cursos r ON r.CodUsuario=u.id LEFT JOIN listadocursos c ON r.CodCurso=c.id ORDER BY u.id ASC")->fetchAll();
        $salida = [];

            foreach($data[$tbl] as $llave => $dato) {
                if($dato['Nombre']) {
                    array_pop($dato);
                    array_push($salida, $dato);
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($salida, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta algo de información: ¿Qué error recibes? ¿qué conexión estás usando (`mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, `PDO`)? ¿Qué es `$database`? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: pon el error que muestra tu server

Comment: En el servidor no puedo ver los errores, es muy limitado y no tiene para mirarlos ya lo he intentado y nada, pero el problema es la función fetchAll() la cambie a fetch() y me devolvio un resultado, pero los necesito todos

Comment: ¿Puedes poner `error_reporting(E_ALL)` en tu fichero PHP y ver qué error te da?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no me funciona, no los muestra

Comment: Pude ver algo <b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33 bytes)

Comment: El uso que haces de `fetchAll` parece ser inadecuado. Dicho método te pone todos los resultados en un array. **¿Por qué intentas meterlos de nuevo en el array `$salida` en el `foreach`
?** Por otra parte, el Manual recomienda `fetchAll` **solamente** cuando esperas pocos resultados, por lo  mismo, porque se pueden agotar los recursos del servidor. En ese caso tendrías que usar `fetch` y llenar un array recorriendo los resultados. Aquí el problema, creo yo, es un error de comprensión sobre cómo funciona cada método.

Comment: Si lo único que te interesa es la columna `Nombre`, como parece ser, entonces optimiza la consulta: `$sql="SELECT Nombre FROM usuarios u LEFT JOIN cursos r ON r.CodUsuario=u.id LEFT JOIN listadocursos c ON r.CodCurso=c.id ORDER BY u.id ASC";`, luego, si son pocos datos los que esperas, aplica `fetchAll` de este modo: `$salida=$database->query($sql)->fetchAll();` Y ya, **no tienes que manipular más los datos**, tendrás en `$salida` todos los nombres que trajo la consulta.  Si son muchos registros los que se esperan, entonces **usas `fetch` en vez de `fetchAll`** y llenas el array en un bucle.